# Django forms which needs the request , makes testing harder?

Tags: django, forms, testing, request, keyword-argument

I have many django forms in which I pass the request as kwarg.
I've just started dive into testing, and it seems that testing forms which require the request as argument makes the testing harder. As I have to somehow create a request and I cant test my forms without it.

So is it best to avoid passing the request to the form at all? Or another workaround?
The reason I do that on first place is that sometimes I need request.user, or request.session and do some cleaning/setting based on that info in the form.

**UPDATE:**
This is an example form:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
      self.user = self.request.user

   def clean(self):
       # Here I have some cross session-field validation
       if self.request.session['has_response'] and self.cleaned_data('status') == 'NEW':
            raise ValidationError()

   def save(self, commit=False):
      self.instance.user = self.user
      return super(OrderForm, self).save(commit=True)

   class Meta:
      model = Order
      fields = ('address', 'city', 'status', ) # more fields
```

The view code is simple:

```
form = OrderForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

The Order model also have a clean() method with some validation logic.
The session is populated at most during the user login.
The point it I need the session/user there.

But most important, the question - is it a bad design to pass the request and session to the form, considering options for testing this form? I find it more logical when the form take care for saving the object, including the request.user. But maybe I should try to split that between the form and view?

Comment: Could you give an example of your code?  By default render() will use a RequestContext as the context_instance.

Comment: updated a form which closely matching most of my forms behavior.

Comment: Check my recent update for setting sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing request to the form is okay if you need it in the `clean()` method.  You can use a request/session/user in a test like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser, User
from .views import my_view
from .forms import MyForm
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware

# If Python >= 3.4
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
# Else
from mock import patch, MagicMock

class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create a RequestFactory accessible by the entire class.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        # Create a new user object accessible by the entire class.
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='username', 
                                 email='email', password='password')

    def test_my_view(self):
        # Create an instance of a GET request.
        request = self.factory.get('/my-url/')

        # Middleware is not supported so simulate a
        # logged-in user by setting request.user.
        request.user = self.user

        # Or add anonymous user to request.
        request.user = AnonymousUser()

        # Test view() at '/my-url/'
        response = my_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    @patch('app.models.ModelName.save', MagicMock(name="save"))
    def test_my_form_view_with_factory(self):
        # Set up form data.
        form_data = {'something': 'something'}

        # Create an instance of a POST request.
        request = self.factory.post('/my-form-url/', form_data)

        # Simulate logged-in user
        request.user = self.user

        # Setup session.
        middleware = SessionMiddleware()
        middleware.process_request(request)
        request.session.save()

        # Or you should just be able to do
        request.session['somekey'] = 'test'
        request.session.save()           

        # Get response from form view, and test passing 
        # request/data to form.
        form = MyForm(request=request, data=form_data)
        response = my_form_view(request)

        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # If model form you can do 
        self.assertTrue(ModelName.save.called)

    @patch('app.models.ModelName.save', MagicMock(name="save"))
    def test_my_form_view_with_client(self):
        # Use Client instead of RequestFactory.
        self.client = Client()

        # Login with Client.
        self.client.login(username='username', password='password')

        # Set up form data.
        form_data = {'something': 'something'}

        # Get/set session.
        session = self.client.session
        session['somekey'] = 'test'
        session.save()

        # Get response with Client.
        response = self.client.post('/my-form-url/', form_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # If model form you can do 
        self.assertTrue(ModelName.save.called)
```

Should give a general idea of what you can do, not specifically tested.

Comment: The most useful for me is the here RequestFactory. But does this test allow using request.session - or it needs to be stimulated too? considering I need to login in order to test some of my forms, since the login involves setting of some session data

Comment: You can't login with RequestFactory but you can simulate it and set session data.  With Client you can do both. If your custom login view sets session data  a certain way, you can use Client to login with your custom view and it will set the session data.  Or you could use Request factory to do the same with your custom login view.  You could then edit the session data if you needed.  I would try with RequestFactory personally.

Comment: Thanks. Since my forms require user to be logged in, I guess the correct place to stimulate login (which will populate the session) will be in the setUp() ? As this is required before users even access the forms

Comment: Yup, then all the methods in the test class can use it.  Just remember if you need the database to reset between tests you should make separate classes.  You can also use `assertEqual` after logging in to ensure the session is set correctly.

Comment: Separate class seems to fit for me,  think I got it and I can write some tests now. I do think the request in `kwargs` to forms makes tests somewhat more complicated (as you mix some request handling logic), but still possible. Thanks, it was very helpful

Comment: Sure thing.  Good luck with your testing.  A tip, when using assert you can pass a message string as the last argument for assertEqual and assertTrue and in the string you can put the value of the variable you're testing to see where it went wrong.